# PL/SQL dynamic actions

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

having another problem with some PL/SQL code.

My `booking form` currently has a dynamic action applied to the `discount` field. Radio buttons set at `Yes` and `No`. When Yes is clicked it enables the fields `Vouchercode` and `Discountamount`.

What I would like to do is set these fields to `NOT NULL` when `discount = yes`. BUT be `null` if `discount = no`

Thanks

Comment: What doe this have to do with PL/SQL?  You show no code, table schema, or anything useful.  How do you except someone to help you?

Comment: "dynamic action" implies Oracle Apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the Required validation on the `Vouchercode` and `Discountamount` fields depending on whether `discount` is `'Yes'`.

To do this, you change the validation code - you don't need a dynamic action.

e.g. instead of checking if `Vouchercode IS NOT NULL`, change the validation to check `Vouchercode IS NOT NULL OR discount = 'Yes'`.